# Activating colors in links2 (text mode)

Tags: terminal, links

I can't seem to see colors in links2 (text mode), even after playing with my TERM settings. The links2 manpage and README.Debian don't specifically address this issue. Also, command-line options like -html-t-text-color are not recognized in my links2. But I can start and see colors in graphics mode (-g).

My eventual goal is to convert HTML syntax-highlighted document (e.g. JSON or Perl, Javascript, etc) and display them in terminals using ANSI codes for colors.

My platform: Debian Wheezy+Sid AMD64. Terminal emulators used: Konsole (4.6.5). Colors (including 256 colors) work normal for other programs, including emacs and mc.

Any pointers? Thanks in advance. I don't mind using other text-based browsers which support color.

Comment: Use `elinks` instead which supports 256 colours.

Answer (score 1):

If the binary doesn't support the flags advertised by the manpage, check if you are actually executing the right binary. Other links packages or the alternatives system may be interfering.

Comment: Yup, it's /usr/bin/links2 and not a symlink. I also built links 2.7 from source just now and it's the same thing (no color, no -html-t-text-color et al options recognized).

Comment: -html-t-text-color also doesn't work here, regardless of -g / -no-g. But -html-g-text-color is accepted and -g/-no-g work fine. Using Debian/Sid-AMD64 with urxvt.